# handle unnamed JSONP in xmlHttpRequest Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

I have simple **XMLHttpRequest**.

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };

  xhr.send();
```

As you can see that I'm printing this.responseText in the console which outputs something like following

```
({ "status": "success", "data": { "title": "Post1" })
```

How can I get the JSON inside. I am totally aware of **JSONP** concepts but I don't want **$.ajax** in **jQuery**, I'm trying to achieve this via javascript. Thanks

Comment: You need a `callback=functionname` query parameter in the URL.

Comment: And you don't use `XMLHttpRequest` for JSONP. The whole point of JSONP is that you use it for cross-domain requests, which won't work with AJAX.